# Missing wuau.adm policy template from windows\inf folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, gpo, inf

I'm using Windows 10 OS,  I get missing wuau.adm from windows\inf folder. Can I just replace this file from other server or download it, or copy it back from the sysvol folder?

Answer (score 0):

You may replace the file in either the windows\inf directly or replace it in SYSVOL. And you may replace it from another server or download it. Note: *.adm files have long been phased out by Microsoft. Windows 10 should be using *.admx files instead.  Here's a link to the same problem described in the MS TechNet forums.  It is from 2009 and earlier OS but it still applies: [missing wuau.adm from windows\inf folder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d932d94e-b0b5-4c48-a758-813775c89195/missing-wuauadm-from-windowsinf-folder?forum=winserverGP)